# R:: I have a list of vectors, how do I count the number of elements that two vectors have in common for all combinations?

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors...

```
A <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

B <- c("b", "e", "f", "g")

C <- c("c", "f", "g", "h", "i")

listofvectors <- list(A, B, C)
```

How do I check the number of elements that every combination has in common? 
So it would be a matrix of the comparisons, with the number in common. This would give the format as specified by the code

```
output <- matrix(c(5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

dimnames(output) = list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("A", "B", "C"))
#  A B C
#A 5 2 1
#B 2 4 2
#C 1 2 5
```

For individual vectors, I could use `A[A %in% B]` but my actual list has over 300 vectors so doing this for every combination will take a while.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid using loops. I've also seen that the function `combn()` may be useful to complete every permutation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what output you'd expect, can you integrate the expected output in your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could indeed use `combn` as long as `choose(n, 2)` doesn't get too large.

```
common_elements <- combn(listofvectors, 2, 
                         FUN = function(x) intersect(x[[1]], x[[2]]), simplify = FALSE)
names(common_elements) <- vapply(combn(seq_along(listofvectors), 2, simplify = FALSE), 
                                 paste, collapse = "vs", FUN.VALUE = character(1))
#$`1vs2`
#[1] "b" "e"
#
#$`1vs3`
#[1] "c"
#
#$`2vs3`
#[1] "f" "g"
common_num <- lengths(common_elements)
#1vs2 1vs3 2vs3 
#   2    1    2 

library(Matrix)
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/51421029/1412059
fun <- function(x) {
  n <- 0.5 + sqrt(0.25 + 2 * length(x)) #calculate dimension
  i <- sequence(seq_len(n - 1)) #row indices
  j <- rep(seq_len(n - 1), seq_len(n - 1)) + 1 # column indices
  sparseMatrix(i = i, j = j, x = x, triangular = TRUE, dims = c(n, n))
}

output <- fun(common_num)
diag(output) <- lengths(listofvectors)
dimnames(output) <- rep(list(seq_along(listofvectors)), 2)
#3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dtCMatrix"
#  1 2 3
#1 5 2 1
#2 . 4 2
#3 . . 5
```

Comment: This is great! Is there a way of getting the name of the list element rather than its position?

Comment: Yes, but your input list doesn't have names. Simply replace `seq_along` with `names`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood 100%, but maybe that will work for you:

```
l <- list(A,B,C)
sl_ <- seq_along(l)
eg_ <- expand.grid(sl_, sl_)

matrix(mapply(function(x,y) length(intersect(l[[x]],l[[y]])),eg_$Var1, eg_$Var2 ),nrow=length(l))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    5    2    1
# [2,]    2    4    2
# [3,]    1    2    5
```

It's not optimized, so let me know if you have speed or memory issues.

Comment: Works great! Is there a way to get the name of the list element (A, B, C) rather than their position as the index?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being somewhat similar to Roland's approach.

```
m = matrix(NA,nrow=length(listofvectors),ncol=length(listofvectors))

diag(m) = sapply(listofvectors,length)
m[lower.tri(m)] = apply(combn(1:3,2),2,function(x){length(intersect(listofvectors[[x[1]]],listofvectors[[x[2]]]))})
m[upper.tri(m)] = m[lower.tri(m)]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    5    2    1
#[2,]    2    4    2
#[3,]    1    2    5
```